# How to display multiple values in a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I am tasked with creating a nested dictionary, using a comprehension to display the result while using the given list.

For example, given input like

```
given_list = ['iCLA', 'YGU', 'icla YGU', 'Hello World', 'Python']
```

the code should produce:

```
{'iCLA': {'UPPER': ['C', 'L', 'A'], 'lower': ['i']},    
'YGU': {'UPPER': ['Y', 'G', 'U'], 'lower': []},    
'icla YGU': {'UPPER': ['Y', 'G', 'U'], 'lower': ['i', 'c', 'l', 'a']},    
'Hello World': {'UPPER': ['H', 'W'],    
'lower': ['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']},    
'Python': {'UPPER': ['P'], 'lower': ['y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']}}
```

The nested section confused me. I think I should use an if condition to check each letter and place it in a list, but it didn't work for me. How can I write the code?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: If you are given `'iCLA'`, can you write code that produces `{'UPPER': ['C', 'L', 'A'], 'lower': ['i']}`? Do you know how to create a dictionary using a comprehension? If you use a comprehension with the code from the first step, to process the list and create a dictionary, does that solve the problem? If not, exactly what goes wrong? If you understand the steps, please try to put them together, [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the result and **ask a specific question** about what went wrong. Otherwise, figure out what you don't understand, and ask.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please re-read [ask]. "it didn't work for me" is not a problem we can solve: **what happened** when you tried? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? "Any help will be appreciated" [is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), so we cannot answer it. Finally, keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; we are not interested in your level of experience or anything else unrelated to **the question**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks to your comment above, I was able to solve it. I was not aware you could seperate the key in dictionary with comma in comprehension.
Here is my code: 
```{list_value: {"UPPER": [char for char in list_value if char.isupper()],'lower':[char for char in list_value if char.islower()]} for list_value in given_list}```

Comment: It is the same as separating items in a nested data structure, without using a comprehension. The syntax allows you to put an expression for the dict values that will be calculated; a dict with two key-value pairs is an expression, so that works; a list comprehension is also an expression, so that can give the values of the inner dict.

Comment: @karl-knechtel Using comprehensions in that way decreases the performance of the solution because you are double checking each word, so using comprehensions here is inefficient, at least if you use it for the upper/lower part.

Comment: Agreed, but this appears to be a homework assignment. It also won't matter in ordinary code applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done. It loses some efficiency due to checking each character twice, but coefficient loses are no big deal.

```py
d = {
    x: {"UPPER": [c for c in x if c.isupper()], "LOWER": [c for c in x if c.islower()]}
    for x in given_list
}
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'iCLA': {'UPPER': ['C', 'L', 'A'], 'LOWER': ['i']}, 'YGU': {'UPPER': ['Y', 'G', 'U'], 'LOWER': []}, 'icla YGU': {'UPPER': ['Y', 'G', 'U'], 'LOWER': ['i', 'c', 'l', 'a']}, 'Hello World': {'UPPER': ['H', 'W'], 'LOWER': ['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']}, 'Python': {'UPPER': ['P'], 'LOWER': ['y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']}}
```

---

One might think you could improve the time with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but it actually slows it down a bit, even though the character check only happens once per character. However, your best bet is just plain ol' normal loop structure. Comprehension are awesome, but there are cases where it doesn't make sense.

Here you can see the times:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import fmean
import timeit

given_list = ["iCLA", "YGU", "icla YGU", "Hello World", "Python"]


def with_comp(l):
    return {
        x: {
            "UPPER": [c for c in x if c.isupper()],
            "LOWER": [c for c in x if c.islower()],
        }
        for x in given_list
    }


def with_defaultdict(l):
    d = {}
    for x in given_list:
        d[x] = defaultdict(list)
        for c in x:
            d[x]["UPPER"].append(c) if c.isupper() else d[x]["lower"].append(c)
        d[x] = dict(d[x])
    return d

def plain(l):
    d = {}
    for x in given_list:
        d[x] = {"UPPER": [], "lower": []}
        for c in x:
            d[x]["UPPER"].append(c) if c.isupper() else d[x]["lower"].append(c)
    return d


time_with_comp = timeit.repeat(
    stmt="d = with_comp(given_list)", setup="from __main__ import given_list, with_comp"
)
time_with_defaultdict = timeit.repeat(
    stmt="d = with_defaultdict(given_list)",
    setup="from __main__ import given_list, with_defaultdict",
)
time_plain = timeit.repeat(
    stmt="d = plain(given_list)",
    setup="from __main__ import given_list, plain",
)

print("with_comp: {:.2f}".format(fmean(time_with_comp)))
print("with_defaultdict: {:.2f}".format(fmean(time_with_defaultdict)))
print("plain: {:.2f}".format(fmean(time_plain)))
```

which gives times:

```
with_comp: 3.91
with_defaultdict: 4.85
plain: 3.50
```

I'm sure there is an even better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `O(n)` solution by traversing all the letters on each word and checking whether they are lower or upper like this:

```
l = ['iCLA', 'YGU', 'icla YGU', 'Hello World', 'Python']
d = {}

for i in l:
    up, low = [], []
    for a in i:
        if a.islower():
            low.append(a)
        else:
            up.append(a)
    d[i] = {"UPPER":up, "lower":low}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'iCLA': {'UPPER': ['C', 'L', 'A'], 'LOWER': ['i']}, 'YGU': {'UPPER': ['Y', 'G', 'U'], 'LOWER': []}, 'icla YGU': {'UPPER': [' ', 'Y', 'G', 'U'], 'LOWER': ['i', 'c', 'l', 'a']}, 'Hello World': {'UPPER': ['H', ' ', 'W'], 'LOWER': ['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']}, 'Python': {'UPPER': ['P'], 'LOWER': ['y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']}}
```

Comment: I think you meant: `... "lower":low}`

Comment: Is it possible to solve it using dictionary comprehension?

Comment: This does not meet the requirement to use comprehensions, does not adequately explain the approach, and attempts to answer an overly broad question. Since Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please refrain from giving a code-dump answer where there isn't a question more specific than "I have this task, how do I implement the code?".